# TypeError: Cannot read property 'close' of undefined

Tags: node.js, jestjs, koa, supertest

I'm new to nodejs and koa. There is this existing Koa app (running and working fine with no problem) that I am trying to write a test code using Jest. I have searched sample tests that can be possibly applied to this case but to no avail. Now, I have this error  when I run my test code `TypeError: Cannot read property 'close' of undefined`. I know there is something wrong with with my initiation of `server` variable from `ret`.

Btw, `console.log(ret)` returns `undefined`:

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
undefined
Mongoose default connection open to mongodb://localhost/giantsoftdata
Listening to port: 3000
```

Here is the existing app that I want to test with `npm run test`:

```
// index.js
const Koa = require('koa')
const KoaBodyParser = require('koa-bodyparser')
const KoaErrorHandler = require('@giansoft/lib-errors/lib/koaHandler')
const PORT = 3000
const app = new Koa()
const router = require('./api/rest/router')()
const dbconnect = require('./database')
const dbstatus = require('./database/dbstatus')

app
  .use(KoaErrorHandler)
  .use(dbstatus())
  .use(KoaBodyParser())

const ret = dbconnect( async function () {
  app
      .use(router.routes())
      .use(router.allowedMethods())
  app.listen(PORT, () => {
      console.log(`Listening to port: ${PORT}`)
  })
  return app;
})
// console.log(ret)
module.exports = ret;
```

Here is my test code:

```
// index.test.js
const server = require("../index");
const request = require("supertest");

afterEach(() => {
  server.close();
});

describe('routes: /status', () => {
  test('Should respond {Status : "Ok"}.', async () => {
    const response = await request(server).get('/status');
    expect(response.status).toEqual(200);
    expect(response.type).toEqual('application/json');
  });
});
```

Here is the `./database/index.js`

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const dbConfig = require('../config').db

const dbconnect = (callback) => {
  let connString = `mongodb://${dbConfig.host}`
  if (dbConfig.username && dbConfig.password) {
    connString = `mongodb://${dbConfig.username}:${dbConfig.password}@${dbConfig.host}`
  }

  mongoose.connect(connString, { useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true })

  mongoose.connection.on('open', function () {
    callback()
  })

  mongoose.connection.on('connected', function () {
    console.log('Mongoose default connection open to ' + connString)
  })

  mongoose.connection.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log('Mongoose default connection error: ' + err)
  })

  mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', function () {
    console.log('Mongoose default connection disconnected')
  })

  process.on('SIGINT', function () {
    mongoose.connection.close(function () {
      console.log('Mongoose default connection closed through app termination')
      process.exit(0)
    })
  })
}

module.exports = (callback) => {
  dbconnect(callback)
}
```

Comment: Also share code of `require('./database')`

Comment: @front_end_dev updated

Comment: `./database/index.js` dbconnect callback function doesn't return anything and you are expecting `close` method in test script `index.test.js`. That why it's giving `undefined`.

Comment: @front_end_dev so how's is that supposed to be done? pardon my ignorance.

Comment: I have update the `./database/index.js` file and please follow answer.

Answer (score 1):

Updated file - ./database/index.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const dbConfig = require('../config').db

const dbconnect = (callback) => {
  let connString = `mongodb://${dbConfig.host}`
  if (dbConfig.username && dbConfig.password) {
    connString = `mongodb://${dbConfig.username}:${dbConfig.password}@${dbConfig.host}`
  }

  mongoose.connect(connString, { useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true })

  mongoose.connection.on('open', function () {
    callback()
  })

  mongoose.connection.on('connected', function () {
    console.log('Mongoose default connection open to ' + connString)
  })

  mongoose.connection.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log('Mongoose default connection error: ' + err)
  })

  mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', function () {
    console.log('Mongoose default connection disconnected')
  })

  process.on('SIGINT', function () {
    mongoose.connection.close(function () {
      console.log('Mongoose default connection closed through app termination')
      process.exit(0)
    })
  });
  return mongoose.connection;
}

module.exports = (callback) => {
  return dbconnect(callback)
}
```

Comment: perhaps you mean ``return mongoose.Connection``? I still got the same error.

Comment: @tatskie  mongoose.connect return an promise and if connection establised successfully then promise resolve to `undefined`. So i have return the `mongoose.connection` Let's see if it is work.

Comment: it seems to work now. but I encountered a different error here https://imgur.com/Ut3KN33

Comment: Ooops, when I run the app (not the test) I cannot connect anymore to the db. Here is the error:
``Mongoose default connection disconnected
Mongoose default connection error: MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [undefined:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND undefined undefined:27017]``

Comment: @tatskie Can you share your code on github so i can download and run locally. It's difficult to understand the problem by just looking into it.